# Simplify Looped Function And Adding Timed Rate Limit To Promise.all() Request

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, promise, rate-limiting

I have the following function that loops to images and adds the associated images to items. Although it works well, there are two things I am trying to configure but cant get working.

The first issue is I have promise.All(promises) in the function and I want to add a rate limit to it by duration. So not matter if there are 10, 20, 50, 100 promises, I want to set a limit of 60 requests per minute but want all the promises to resolve. Is that possible or do I have to modify my code to use another library or possibly an interval.

The second issue is, if there is a way to simply this functions, that would also help a lot as It seems to be too many loops and might slow the api down. Any improvements to the code will be appreciated

```
function findImagesForObjectsOrGenerate(listOfObjects, images, isCategory, merchantId) {
  let promises = [];
  if (listOfObjects.length > 0) {
    listOfObjects.forEach((object) => {
      const matchedImage = images.find(image => {
        return object.id === image.cloverDataId;
      });

      if (matchedImage) {
        object.imageData = matchedImage.imageData;
      } else {
        promises.push(imageService.generateImageByNameAndSave(object.name, isCategory, object.id, merchantId));
      }
    })
  }
  return Promise.all(promises).then(values => {
    values.forEach((response, i) => {
      if (response) {
        listOfObjects[i].imageData = response.imageData;
      }
    })
    return listOfObjects;
  });
}
```